# How to scrape reddit posts that did not make front page with python, PRAW/PSAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Ok so this is a bit of a weird situation,

I am trying to get a dataset of reddit posts that didn't hit the front page, only requirements are that it didn't get to front page and was posted within the last 3 years.

I am trying to achieve a truly random spread so can't be in any order.

Using PSAW I have the following code

```
start_epoch = int(datetime(2017, 1, 1).timestamp())

gen = api.search_submissions(after=start_epoch, limit=500)
```

This code here however still needs to filter out front page posts and make the results random not by post date how can I do this?

Is this the best way any other recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: It's more or less impossible to figure out whether a post reached the front page, unless you happen to have a record of the front page sampled over your whole period of time (which PushShift might have, though I don't know). It would be much easier to filter out all posts above a certain score.

Comment: @jarhill0 I was thinking that might be it, I can find an average threshold for front page posts and use that, however the problem of randomness remains as pushshift return results in date or karma order. Is there any way to randomize these results?

Comment: Reddit itself lets you get a random post from a subreddit, but those seem to be biased towards recent and high-scoring posts. If PushShift has a similar feature, that may be an easy way to do it. Otherwise the only thing I can think of is to get **all** posts from your date random and then use `random.choice` on the list, which seems horrifically inefficient/wasteful (since you're fetching thousands of posts and throwing almost all of them away).

Comment: I think it would be infeasible to fetch 3 years of reddit submissions to filter them down to just a few hundred

Comment: You could generate a random date within a range and then select the first post after that time that meets your criteria. That's not quite truly random, but might be good enough.

Comment: Thats a good point I might try that and see how I go.

Comment: I had a try but I can't get the randomness I require, if anyone has any ideas im all ears.